# Plotly: How to always show the lowest bar in front in overlay bar charts

Tags: python, plotly

In the following plot, the blue bar for Jan 2nd is not showing, because the red bar is drawn on top of it and has a higher value. How can I display the blue bar even when it has a lower value than the red?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=2, freq="D"), 'value': [40,20]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=2, freq="D"), 'value': [20,40]})

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=df['date'], y=df['value']),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=df2['date'], y=df2['value']),
])

fig.update_layout(barmode='overlay')
fig.show()
```

Plot:
[image: Plot]

Comment: Try this:`fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')`

Comment: @r-beginners That does not work since if you use `barmode='stack'` it will put the bars on top of each other (stack them) making the y-axis value wrong.

Comment: So how about grouping them together? `fig.update_layout(barmode='group')`

Comment: `barmode='group'` works but will get messy if you have a lot of columns and a lot of data points - that is why I wanted them overlayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- with data preparation this can be achieved by using `base` argument as well
- combine all data into one data frame
- calculate *base* for each observation of *date* (the x-axis)
- calculate *value* minus *base*
- use **Plotly Express** as it is simpler API and control *hover* so inner workings to make this work are not displayed

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"date": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=2, freq="D"), "value": [40, 20]}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    data={"date": pd.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=2, freq="D"), "value": [20, 40]}
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=df2['date'], y=df2['value']),
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=df['date'], y=df['value']),
])

fig.update_layout(barmode='overlay')
fig.show()

# concat all data with a column that defines color
df = pd.concat([df.assign(name="SF Zoo"), df2.assign(name="LA Zoo")])
# given x is date and y is value, calculate base each bar
df = (
    df.sort_values(["date", "value"])
    .groupby("date")
    .apply(lambda d: d.assign(base=d["value"].shift()))
    .fillna(0)
)
# calculate how high it should be
df = df.assign(y=lambda d: d["value"] - d["base"])
# now simple to achieve with plotly express
px.bar(
    df,
    x="date",
    y="y",
    color="name",
    base="base",
    hover_data={"y": False, "base": False, "value": True},
).update_layout(barmode="overlay")
```

[image]